# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1241

I have this complex query that gives me `Operand should contain 1 column(s)` error when executing. I know that this error means there are some un-needed brackets but I dont know which ones.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 deals 
WHERE 
 country_id = 2 AND 
 (city_id = 4 OR city_id = 0) AND 
 section_id = 2 AND 
 id IN (
  SELECT 
   deal_id 
  FROM 
   deal_repeat 
  WHERE 
   start_date = '2013-06-14') AND 
   business_id IN (
    SELECT 
     *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('51') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-114') ) + sin( radians('51') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM 
     address 
    HAVING 
     distance < '25'
   ) 
  ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: `AND business_id IN (SELECT *, 3959...` is causing the error because you're selecting more than one column in the subquery - you need to select just one column (the corresponding business ID from "address").

Answer (score 2):

instead of this

```
  AND business_id IN (SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos(
```

do this

```
 AND business_id IN (SELECT  ( 3959 * acos(
```

as `Jonathan` said : SELECT * returns all the columns and you should select one column to select business_id

Comment: +1. This is what I saw as the problem. And for an explanation for OP, subqueries generally should only return one column. Saying `SELECT *` returns all the columns.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn edited and added your suggest :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structures, this is a little difficult to answer.  The problem is that you're filtering by business_id being in a list of multiple columns (select *).  The subquery should only contain a single column (a list of business ids's presumably). Instead, assuming you have a business id field in your address table, then this might be what you're looking for.

```
SELECT * 
FROM deals 
WHERE country_id = 2 
    AND city_id IN (4,0) 
    AND section_id = 2 
    AND id IN (
        SELECT deal_id 
        FROM deal_repeat 
        WHERE start_date = '2013-06-14') 
   AND business_id IN (
        SELECT business_id 
        FROM address 
        WHERE 3959*acos(cos(radians('51')) * 
            cos(radians(lat)) * 
            cos(radians(lng)-radians('-114'))+sin(radians('51')) * 
            sin(radians(lat)))  < '25') 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: thanks that was the solution

Comment: @TarekAbdElMonsif -- np, glad I could help!